# How to use submit on each table row with Form::model laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following along with a Udemy course learning laravel, however the instructor wraps a Form::model around multiple elements. This makes the submit button unresponsive. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean to say submit button is not responsive compare to other? It's displayed small right? If the issue is that then try to remove `btn-sm` class from submit button!

Comment: Problem should be `@foreach ($blog as $blog)`

Comment: @Tpojka That's what I thought too at first. But I changed it to ($blog as $bg) and used $bg inside the foreach, did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what course you're talking about. either way laravelcollective package doesn't change the view, only helps making it easier to show submitted data. you can only use Form::model and Form::close() but use normal html for inside of your form and use bootstrap or whatever in it

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work either. However I noticed when I inspected the elements, the closing </form> tag was not being created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the `<form>` outside of the `<table`>.
Whenever you put the `<form>` inside `<tbody>` it will be closed immediately. Check the HTML in Chrome debugger.

There are several approach you can try:

1. Create a hidden `<form id="data1">` and `<form id="data2">` and so on. When submit button is hit, use Javascript to determine what form id you should submit and call `document.getElementById(form_id).submit();`
2. Each time the submit button is hit. Use JS to construct a form with corresponding data, append it to the document and submit it.